# Apache does not start on EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a t2.medium ec2 instance which runs apache. Everything was fine till today morning but suddenly apache stopped working and does not restart again.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-46 ~]$ sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [FAILED]
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-46 ~]$ service httpd start
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Then we checked where port 80 is already listening.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-46 ~]$ sudo netstat -tupln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2204/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2392/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38935               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2225/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2714/sendmail
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2664/mysqld
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      2204/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2392/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::46232                    :::*                        LISTEN      2225/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               2090/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               2204/rpcbind
udp        0      0 172.31.3.46:123             0.0.0.0:*                               2416/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               2416/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               2416/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51407               0.0.0.0:*                               2225/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:683                 0.0.0.0:*                               2204/rpcbind
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:708               0.0.0.0:*                               2225/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                                    2204/rpcbind
udp        0      0 :::683                      :::*                                    2204/rpcbind
udp        0      0 :::40147                    :::*                                    2225/rpc.statd
```

But there is no sign of port 80 in this.

We need to go live today but this has posed a major problem? Can someone please suggest what to do?

Comment: First, it's not StackOverflow question. Second, use `sudo` Finally, if this requires you to ask for help - you are not ready to go live today

Comment: I have tried both with and without sudo.

Comment: (a) Check error log during httpd restart (`/var/log/httpd/error*`); (b) try `apache2ctl configtest`; (c) If nothing works, you might want to shutdown this instance & spin up a new one; (d) I would agree with @Felix, if you need to ask help on this, its bad idea to go live today!

Comment: Can you paste content of "/etc/apache2/ports.conf"

Answer (score 0):

Try this: pidof httpd or pidof apache2 (depending on the distro running on that t2micro aws instance). If it returns any pid then kill that pid or those pids manually issuing a kill -9 pid then try restarting apache. If that doesn't work you should investigate the apache logs. That should give you more info about what is preventing apache to start and a possible way to fix the issue so you can start apache. Deploying a new instance is not going to help you to start the apache on your current instance and/or figure out the current issue.